# specific sequence of matrices making a strange ratio of matrix norms diverging

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, matrix-analysis, operator-norms

For any $t>0$ define $d_t:=\operatorname{diag}j^t=\operatorname{diag}(1^t,2^t,\ldots)$. Now pick up such a $t>0$ and an arbitrary $\theta\in\big(0,\frac12\big)$. For every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ find finitely many self-adjoint matrices $x_{k,1},x_{k,2},\ldots,x_{k,n_k}$ (arbitrary size) such that $\frac{\big\|\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}(d_tx_{k,j}d_t)^2\big\|_{\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)}}{\big\|\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}d_{2t+\theta}x_{k,j}^2d_{2t+\theta}\big\|_{\mathcal{B}(\ell_2)}}$ tends to infinity as $k\to\infty$.

The point is to get it for $\theta$ close to one half.